# Вопрос по ООП для гуру, есть пример

Tags: ооп, проектирование

Задание от заказчика:

- Человек, который должен смотреть на другого человека.

Делаем Human и метод lookAt(Human)

Заказчик добавляет:

- Люди могут видеть по разному (дальтоники).

Добавляем фильтр отображения в человека Bitmap BitmapFilter.filter(Bitmap)

Заказчик добавляет:

- Камера может видеть человека.

Делаем Camera и метод lookAt(Human). Понимаем, что нужно перевернуть зависимость, и делаем у человека Human.show(IHumanViewer), а камера и другой человек реализует этот интерфейс.

Заказчик добавляет:

- Человек может быть не видим для камеры (ну мало-ли)

Делаем свойство человека visible. Дальше камера его проверяет.

Вот тут некрасиво получается, что интерфейс отображение приобретает вид: IHumanViewer.show(Bitmap, visibility)

Не нравится, то, что классы незаинтерисованые в видимости объекта, обязаны зависеть от параметра visibility.
Кто знает как обойти это?

Comment: Заказчик добавляет - "камера теперь отслеживает и гусей!". Используйте interface segregation. И если уж делаете по объектам реальной жизни - то вводите понятие "место/scene", на которую смотрит камера. И проводите обработку через него, в стиле "человек появился на сцене - все кто смотрит на сцену его увидели". И вообще не пытайтесь применть ООП на примерах "из головы" - всегда можно посмотреть на архитектуру, и нарочно выдвинуть требование, которое ее поломает. В реальной ситуации требования появляются не "вопреки архитектуре" - они вообще от нее не зависят.

Comment: Я просто решил смоделировать упоротые требования. Можно другой вариант. Есть документ, он хранит позиции с ценой и количеством. Документ можно закрыть, сериализовать, напечатать, применить скидку и т.д. Никак не сделать так, чтоб интерфейс документа не распухал и скрыть внутренности документа от служб.
Это ООП головного мозга не решаемо.

Comment: Всё очень просто. Заказчик: «Я хочу, чтобы ваш танк ещё и летал!» Вы: «Нужна переделка архитектуры, стоимость и время разработки проекта возрастёт на 25%.» Заказчик: «А можно то же, но бесплатно и без увеличения времени?» Вы: «Вы просите вместо танка самолёт. Мне придётся переписать всю архитектуру. Ваши первоначальные требования были очень далеки от нынешних, и вы превысили заложенный лимит эластичности архитектуры. Так что ответ отрицательный.»

Comment: Чувак можешь свой вариант написать на pozitiffcat2@gmail.com? Или на pastebin

Comment: @АлексейМальченко: Если вы хотите, чтобы вам приходили ещё ответы — подождите, пока вопрос переоткроют. (Или сделайте его лучше.)

Comment: "Документ можно закрыть, сериализовать, напечатать, применить скидку и т.д." - документ этим и не должен заниматься (кроме, возможно, первого), сериализацию делает сериализатор, печать - принтер, скидка - еще одно третье лицо.

Comment: Мне придется раскрывать внутренности документа, не хотелось бы

Answer (score 2):

Summary: Для простых случаев, в которых бизнес-логика хорошо ложится на свойства объектов, вполне можно сделать её внутри объектов. Если вы замечаете, что вам приходится делать неестественные штуки, или ваши требования сложны, вынесите логику в отдельный объект.

Здесь полная аналогия с кодом обыкновенной функции: если часть вычислений в функции становится сложной, её выгружают в отдельную специализированную функцию.

---

(Ни в коей мере не являюсь специалистом в ООП.)

Инверсия смотрится как-то ненатурально. Давайте пусть объекты ведут себя как в реальности. Например, так:

```
interface IHasImage { Bitmap GetImage(); }

// дальтоник - проблема восприятия, а не передачи
class Human : IHasImage
{
    BitmapFilter filter;
    public Human(ColorBlindnessType cbt)
    {
        filter = Helper.CreateColorBlindFilter(cbt);
    }

    Bitmap LookAt(IHasImage o)
    {
        var image = o.GetImage();
        if (filter)
            image = filter(image);
        return image;
    }

    Bitmap GetImage() { return CurrentlyVisible ? m_Image : null; }

    // очевидно, нельзя быть невидимым только для камеры
    // невидимость - для всех
    bool CurrentlyVisible { get; protected set; }
}

class Camera
{
    Bitmap LookAt(IHasImage o) { return o.GetImage(); }
}
```

Возможно, `LookAt` нужно тоже сделать интерфейсом.

---

Окей, условия изменились. Теперь человека может видеть только колдун. Не проблема:

```
interface IHasCommonImage { Bitmap GetImage(); }
interface IHasTrueImage : IHasCommonImage { Bitmap GetTrueImage(); }

class Human : IHasTrueImage
{
    Bitmap LookAt(IHasTrueImage o) { return o.GetImage(); }

    Bitmap GetImage() { return CurrentlyVisible ? m_Image : null; }
    Bitmap GetTrueImage() { return m_Image; }
    bool CurrentlyVisible { get; protected set; }
}

class Clairvoyant : Human
{
    override Bitmap LookAt(IHasTrueImage o) { return o.GetTrueImage(); }
}
```

---

В случае, когда бизнес-логика становится размазанной по объектам, нужно собрать её в отдельную сущность, занимающуюся этой самой бизнес-логикой.

```
interface IHasImage { Bitmap GetImage(); }
interface ICustomVisibility { bool IsVisible { get; } }
interface ILooker { Bitmap LookAt(IHasImage o); }
interface IClairvoyant { }

class Human : IHasImage, ICustomVisibility
{
    Bitmap LookAt(IHasImage o) { return SightManager.Look(this, o); }

    Bitmap GetImage() { return m_Image; }
    bool IsVisible { get; protected set; }
}

class Wizard : Human, IClairvoyant
{
}

static class SightManager
{
    public static Bitmap Look(ILooker subj, IHasImage obj)
    {
        // тут вся бизнес-логика:
        // если смотрит колдун
        if (subj is IClairvoyant)
            return obj.GetImage(); // то видит как есть
        // если не колдун, а объект невидимый
        else if (obj is ICustomVisibility && !((ICustomVisibility)obj).IsVisible)
            return null; // но ничего не видит
        else
            // случай без магии
            return obj.GetImage();
    }
}
```

Это не нарушает принципов ООП, наоборот, у вас бизнес-логика ушла в отдельную сущность.

Comment: Что делать, когда камера не может видеть невидимых людей, а люди видят не видимых. Это значит ответственность лежит на клиентских классах, а не в методе Human.GetImage(). Нет так не пойдет.

Comment: @АлексейМальченко: Это не называется тогда «невидимый». В ООП правильное название очень важно. А кто определяет, видит данная камера данного человека?

Comment: Ну допустим я выбрал данную метафору. Человек имеет свойство видимости. Ну шапку невидимку он одел например )))) и простые смертные его не видят, а колдуны видят )))

Comment: @АлексейМальченко: Окей, обновил ответ. (Дальтонизм см. в первой части.)

Comment: Это лишь простейший пример разнообразных требований. Неужели на каждый высер мы будем трогать интерфейс человека. Что-то здесь не так...
Видимо нет в такой ситуации верного решения.

Comment: @АлексейМальченко: А в чём проблема? Да, поменялись требования — поменялись и интерфейсы. Это само собой разумеется. Вы ж не жалуетесь, что пришлось добавить свойство видимости? ЗЫ: Если уж очень хочется, сделайте отдельный `ImageManager`, закодируйте бизнес-логику в нём, и всё чтение картинок зараутите через него. Но я бы так не делал.

Comment: Получается, что абсолютно всегда нужно обработку выделять в сервисный класс, что бы не бояться изменения требований, и упоротую логику хранить в нем. Но это какой-то процедурный подход ИМХО.

Comment: @АлексейМальченко: А почему вы боитесь изменения кода при изменении требований? У вас было требование построить деревенский туалет, оно превратилось в требование построить дворец. Ясно, что всё поменялось. Не абсолютизируйте эджайл, серьёзные изменения требований **обязаны** приводить к изменению архитектуры.

Comment: @shatal: Я говорю немного не об этом. Если изменение небольшое и «пролезает» в архитектуру — значит, его и надо делать в рамках текущей архитектуры. Понятно, архитектуру надо делать немного «на вырост». Если не пролезает — значит, архитектуру надо менять, это тоже очевидно. Делать архитектуру так, чтобы она выдержала **любое** изменение, невозможно.

Comment: @shatal: Я прочитал вашу критику. А теперь покажите ваш **код**.